# MySQL procedure with SELECT returns entire table

Tags: mysql, procedures

I try to write a stored procedure that finds the user in table and returns him.
But the procedure always returns entire table.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `login`
CREATE PROCEDURE `login`(IN login VARCHAR(20), IN password VARCHAR(32))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = login AND `password` = password;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try change the names of parameters

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `login`;
CREATE PROCEDURE `login`(IN alogin VARCHAR(20), IN apassword VARCHAR(32))
SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = alogin AND `password` = apassword;
```

Ans since it's a one-statement SP dith `BEGIN...END` block and no need to change a `DELIMITER`.